# Move an folder outside the current folder

Tags: filesystem

So for example I'm in this folder `desktop/game`, and in the game folder there is `backup`, and what I want to do is move the folder from `game` to desktop while being inside the dir.

Answer (score 2):

If you're in `desktop/game` and want to move `desktop/game/backup` back to `desktop`, you can use `..`, which is a special filename that means "the parent folder of this folder." So

```
mv backup ../
```

will **m**o**v**e backup to the current working directory's parent directory.

If there is already a file or folder called `desktop/backup`, this *will* overwrite it. If you want to be sure not to overwrite anything, you can add the `-n` flag, which will prevent overwriting altogether, or the '-i' flag, which will warn you if you are about to overwrite something. You would use those like this:

```
mv -i backup ../
```

**Be sure** to include the `/` at the end, otherwise it will overwrite your entire desktop folder with `backup`, which would be very bad.

If you want to be *very* sure, you can use full paths, ie `/home/<my_user>/desktop/game...`, and those work equally well no matter what folder you're in.

Answer (score 0):

from the game directory, as in your example:
mv backup ~/Desktop.
Or from your file manager, drill down to the game directory and cut & paste backup to Desktop. voila.